# Working with SSRS dynamic fields

Tags: reporting-services, pivot-table, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS matrix table is a great way to generate dynamic fields as long as values exist.

However, is there a way to "always" show these dynamic fields even if a value doesn't exist for them?  The report field locations varies based on data availability and users have to add missing columns in Excel manually.

Dynamic fields go from 3 to up to 30 (at least for now based on run by values).  Adding these values manually would make the report hard to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have handled for this is in the SQL.  I build a table of all the values I will always want, I cross join that table to my final output table and update/insert values where they need to exist.  That way I guarantee the rows, and eventually columns in the matrix, exists even if they end up being null.

Does that make sense?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` works well for this. You can also `UNION` distinct values to the results if you want to avoid issues with records not fitting into predefined combinations.

Comment: This makes sense.  Very ideal solution.  I'd rather maintain it in SQL than in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

Jesse's solution is a good one, but if for whatever reason you can't or prefer not to change the SQL you can do it in SSRS by forcing a blank value in the cell with a expression like this:

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!.xxx.Value)," ",Fields!.xxx.Value)
```